# Running postgres_database.present a second time causes error "has wrong parameters which couldn't be changed on fly"

Tags: postgresql, saltstack

Running a salt state that looks like the following to create a postgres database for django...

```
django-db:
  postgres_database.present:
  - encoding: 'UTF-8'
  - owner: djangouser
  - db_user: postgres
```

When I run it the first time, so far, so good:

```
      ID: django-db
Function: postgres_database.present
  Result: True
 Comment: The database django-db has been created
 Started: 20:59:01.148225
Duration: 494.007 ms
 Changes:
          ----------
          django-db:
              Present
```

But when I run it again, the result is an error:

```
      ID: django-db
Function: postgres_database.present
  Result: False
 Comment: Database django-db has wrong parameters which couldn't be changed on fly.
 Started: 21:04:14.289538
Duration: 101.216 ms
 Changes:
```

Answer (score 2):

Credit to user martin_ on IRC, The problem is the hyphen in 'UTF-8'. The state should be

```
django-db:
  postgres_database.present:
  - encoding: 'UTF8'
  - owner: djangouser
  - db_user: postgres
```

http://irclog.perlgeek.de/salt/2014-08-30/text

Comment: This is still valid in 2020 :)